# where should i call the setintreval in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, setinterval

I am trying to call getSession() every 5sec of delay. But in initial render i would like to call this function and execute immediately.

According to my below code, in the initial render itself it is using the delay of 5sec to display the output.

How can i achieve the following:
1. Initial render should be done immediately
2. after every 5sec getSession() should be called as well.

Current Results: 
It is taking 5sec delay to display in initial render.

Expected results:
Initial render should be done immediately.

```
componentDidMount() {
     this.getSession();
 }

 getSession() {
     var path = "Sharing.aspx/GetSessions";
     setInterval(() => {
         axios
             .post(path, { withCredentials: true })
             .then(response => {
                 let element = response.data.d;
                 this.setState({
                     sessions: element
                 });
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 this.setState({
                     Errors: error
                 });
                 console.error(error);
             });
     },5000
     );
 }

 render() {
     return (
         <div>
             {this.renderSessionDetails()}
         </div>
         );
 }
```

Expected results:
Initial render should be done immediately. 
After every 5sec getSessions() should be called.

Comment: You can call `this.getSession()` in your `constructor` and then call `setInterval` in the `componentDidMount` !

Comment: i tried this now, but without manual refreshing of the page, the values aren't getting updated.

Comment: i mean.. initial render when no other user connected to same server, it should print "no session available" and when another user logs into same server, the table gets updated on user 1 and describes who has joined..

Comment: componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => { this.getSession, 5000 });

    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeSessions : {}
        };
        this.getSession();
    }

Comment: can you put this.renderSessionDetails() method in comments or in question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go about refactoring your code to look like that, in order to avoid waiting initially for those 5 seconds. The refactor is mainly about extracting the fetching logic away from the timer implementation. Please note that inside `componentDidMount()` we first call `this.getSession()` immediately, which is fine because we eliminated the intervals from it. Then we dispatch the intervals.

```js
class Component extends React.Component() {
  intervalId = null

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSession()
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.getSession(), 5000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.intervalId) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId)
    }
  }

  getSession() {
    var path = 'Sharing.aspx/GetSessions'

    axios
      .post(path, { withCredentials: true })
      .then(response => {
        let element = response.data.d
        this.setState({
          sessions: element
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          Errors: error
        })
        console.error(error)
      })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderSessionDetails()}</div>
  }
}
```

I would also try to make sure we're not running into race conditions here. But, if you're sure your requests never take more than 5 seconds -- it should be fine. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
const INTERVAL = 6000;

class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSession();
    this.intervalId = window.setInterval(() => this.getSession(), INTERVAL);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  getSession() {
    var path = "Sharing.aspx/GetSessions";
    setInterval(() => {
      axios
        .post(path, { withCredentials: true })
        .then(response => {
          let element = response.data.d;
          this.setState({
            sessions: element
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({
            Errors: error
          });
          console.error(error);
        });
    }, 5000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderSessionDetails()}</div>;
  }
}
```

`ComponentDidMount` will be called only once, and at that point, you call the first `getSession` call, and start the `interval`.

An important thing to bring attention to is the call to `window.clearInterval` when the component gets unmounted. This is to make sure that interval doesn't keep running eternally, and worst, that more than one `interval` run in parallel after having this component mount a couple of times.

I hope it helps.